# ¿Cómo exportar datos de sql a excel?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, excel

estoy siguiendo un ejemplo para exportar mis datos hacia una hoja excel; el tema aquí es que en ese vídeo se utiliza base de datos access y yo estoy usando sql server, entonces al momento de que hago la conexión hacia el archivo excel tengo que poner un proveedor y no cual sea en caso de sql server, en el vídeo el proveedor que ponen es:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\MyExcel.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
```

trate sin proveedor y me salió este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi línea de código es la siguiente:

```
Dim cadena As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Sql; data source=c:/users/cardenas/desktop/Practica.xslx; extended properties=Excel 8.0;"
```

Cúal sería el proveedor adecuado que debo poner

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Depende del proveedor de conexión que vayas a utilizar, el nombre puede variar.

Para el Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server se usa:

- MSOLEDBSQL

Para SQL Server Native Client 11.0 OLE DB Provider

- SQLNCLI11

Si quieres ejemplos, puedes encontrarlos en https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/